# How exactly use Filter to validate login

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

When I Run my application, my filter is always running at first, how can I validate a login and calls my filter only after the submit,and how exactly can I check data in Filter?

My Filter

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                     FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    System.out.println("I'm in the filter");
    HttpServletRequest request2 = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpSession session = request2.getSession();
    Object obj = (Object) session.getAttribute("user");

    if(obj==null) {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("ErrorPage.html").forward(request,response);
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(request,response);
    }}
```

My Post Form

```
<form action="LoginServlet" method="POST">
<div class="imgcontainer">
    <img src="img_avatar2.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
</div>

<% System.out.println("Entrei no Login"); %>

<div class="container">
    <%--@declare id="uname"--%><%--@declare id="psw"--%><label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>

    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

    <button type="submit">Login</button>

</div>

<div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
    <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>

</div>
```

My question  is, how the filter is used to validate a login? I mean, I feel it's so much easier to only use a Servlet, and compare the username and password, I'm not understanding exactly how the submit form will be processed in filter.

Should/Could I  send the submit form directly to a Filter or I do need an servlet in the middle of this comunication?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to know that there are libraries that help you avoid this boiler plate code, but in some cases you have to write it on your own.
A filter is a code that is executed whenever you request an URL and has some rules that you can choose, and redirects you to a resource. You can define whatever rule you need to let access to a resource. Normally what you should do is find a User Id (normally from cookies) and look for his roles, each role has its resources that he can access to. Normally it should be stored in a database. If for example a defined user has role : ROLE_ADMIN , and ROLE_ADMIN has access to home page, then user should access to that home page. If that user doesn't have role (or not active user , if you would like) , the filter can redirect to an Unauthorized page that you define. Bear in mind that you can use sessions to store a user access, you don't have to call a repository service every time a user request a resource. This is a general idea about how you can do it, if you need any details you can check this links :

> https://www.baeldung.com/intercepting-filter-pattern-in-java
>
> https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/servlet/java-servlet-filter-example/
>
> https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html